# element wise multiplication in r

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

Is there an inbuilt function or operator to do the following in R :

```
ElementwiseMultiply <- function ( a_, b_ )
{
c_ = a_ ;
for ( i in 1:ncol(a_) )
{
    c_[,i] = ( a_[,i] * b_ ) ;
}
return ( c_ );
}
```

For instance

```
> a_
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    2
> b_
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   -1
[3,]    1
> ElementwiseMultiply ( a_, b_ )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    8
[2,]   -2   -3
[3,]    3    2
```

Comment: It seems like you are coming from C++ background and thus the "loop" way of thinking. R is a vectorized language and you usually can avoid loops unlseed each entry supplies diffirent conditions. There is a workaround though for C++ users in the Rcpp package. Take a look [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/728/switching-from-c-to-r-limitations-applications)

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are right :). However I tried * and %*%. Operator * worked when a_ has one column.

Comment: `*` and `%*%` are different things. The first is just multiplyinh each element of first vector to its corresponding element in the second, while latter is a matrix multiplication

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, normal multiplication with `b_` as a vector:

```
a_*as.vector(b_)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    8
[2,]   -2   -3
[3,]    3    2
```